# Cannot get the specific XML node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I want to update the xml node and searched the site to find the example at [this link](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/1341.html). However I get the error on Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Would someone show me how to get the node. Thanks in advance

This is my vb code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.IO

Partial Class test2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load      

    Dim xmlFileNamae As String = "Vancouver.xml"
    Dim xmlFilePath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("XMLFolder") & xmlFileNamae
    If File.Exists(xmlFilePath) Then
        Dim docXML As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        docXML.Load(xmlFilePath)
        Dim ID As String = "1"
        Dim node As XmlNode = docXML.SelectSingleNode("/Orders/Order[@ID='" & ID & "']/Date")
        node.InnerText = Date.Now
        node = docXML.SelectSingleNode("/Orders/Order[@ID='" & ID & "']/Country")
        node.InnerText = "Vancouver"
        docXML.Save(xmlFilePath)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

There is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Orders>
    <order ID="2">
      <item>Organ</item>
      <Date>7/24/2014 3:50:42 PM</Date>
      <Country>China</Country>
    </Order>
   <order ID="1">
     <item>Apple</item>
     <Date>7/24/2014 3:50:42 PM</Date>
     <Country>China</Country>
   </order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: Which line raising error?

Comment: can you elaborate on which line the error is being thrown? At 1st look, I think the `xmlFilePath` is not well initialised `& xmlFileNamae` which might have been wrongly written, which will cause the `.Load()` to throw error.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK , it throw on this line Dim node As XmlNode = docXML.SelectSingleNode("/Files/File[@ID='" & ID & "']/Date"). the node is nothing

Comment: @Fabio "Dim node As XmlNode = docXML.SelectSingleNode("/Files/File[@ID='" & ID & "']/Date")" cause error because the node is not found. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your XML is broken - You close the first `order` with `Order`, which is wrong.

Second thing, your XPath is not good as well.

Here are both of the XPaths with a "cleaner" code.

```
    Dim XmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim Node As XmlNode
    XmlDoc.Load(//Your path)
    //This will give you the date of the first order item in orders
    //where the ID attribute equals 1.
    Node = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Orders/order[@ID="1"]/Date")
    //Do somehintg
    //This will give you the country of the first order item in orders
    //where the ID attribute equals 1.
    Node=XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Orders/order[@ID="1"]/Country")
    //Do something else.
```